# M<->ove application to another windows

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, multiple-monitors

in OSX snow leopard,
How can I move a window into another monitor using keyboard only?
and how can I set the primary monitor, so every time I start an app, it will default on that set monitor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) - it allows window maniuplation by keystrokes. Nifty little app.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, OSX version of Ultramon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out myself: [See similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/82758/how-do-i-force-quicktime-to-open-on-a-second-monitor).  The best I've been able to do is to use AppleScript to set the bounds of the front window of the application so it puts it on the second monitor. `set bounds of front window to {2460, 256, 3299, 736}`.

In my case I'm launching movies from iTunes in Quicktime so starting with an AppleScript makes sense anyways but it might not be appropriate for you:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set sel to item 1 of selection
    set loc to (get location of sel)
end tell
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    open loc
    activate
    set bounds of front window to {2460, 256, 3299, 736}
    present front document
    play front document
end tell
```